# How to pass nested attribute values in controller for rails 3.2.8 app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, nested-attributes

`quote` gets the test item from `rfq` which is known when a quote is created (in `@rfq.test_items`). Table quote_test_items stores all test items for a quote (`@quote.quote_test_items`).

In `quote` model, there is :

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :quote_test_items, :reject_if => proc {|item| item['test_item_id'].blank? }, :allow_destroy => true
```

We want all test items in `rfq` to be passed into `quote` in controller `new` and show them to user if he/she wants to remove some test items. Here is what we did in quote controller `new`:

```
@rfq.test_items.each do |it|
     @quote.quote_test_items.build
     @quote.quote_test_items << it
end
```

There is an error:

```
QuoteTestItem(#56736972) expected, got TestItem(#50178372)
```

We tried the following in controller `new`:

```
@quote.test_items << @rfq.test_items
```

It generates no error in controller. However there is an error (undefined method :test_item_id) in view for the code below:

```
<%= f.fields_for @quote.quote_test_items  do |builder| %>
        <ul>
          <div class="fields">
            <li><%= builder.input :test_item_id, :collection => TestItem.active_test_item.all(:order => 'name'), :label_method => :name, :value_method => :id,
                                  :label => false %><%= link_to_remove_items "remove", f %></li>   
          </div>
        </ul>
    <% end %>
```

What's the right way to pass the nested attribute values in controller? Thanks for the help.

Comment: can you try change `@quote.quote_test_items` to `:quote_test_items`?

Comment: Changed to :quote_test_items in f.fields_for. There is no error (undefined method ...) after change. But there is nothing showing. The issue is still that there is nothing passed into the quote.quote_test_items in controller new to show.

Comment: Here is the working code in controller: @rfq.test_items.each do |it|
     @quote.quote_test_items.build(:test_item_id => it.test_item_id)
end